# How to bind to a field without specifying Path or Datacontext?

Tags: c#, wpf

**Note:** The whole source code contains multiple files and 100s of lines of code so, I can't post everything here. The complete source code is available at this [Github Repo](https://github.com/SingletonSean/reservoom/tree/master/src)

---

I am new to WPF and following books to gather knowledge. So far, in all the example of books, I have seen that either we need to specify the `ElementName + Path` or have a DataContext for binding.

But in a [Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2FPFgW0xVB0&list=PLA8ZIAm2I03hS41Fy4vFpRw8AdYNBXmNm&index=5) (with [Source Code at GIT](https://github.com/SingletonSean/reservoom), the UI elements are binded to the fields directly without specifying any DataContext. For example, in the code snippet below, the `Text` attribute of the `TextBox` has been binded to `Username` without specifying any DataContext or Path:

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0 25 0 0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Username" />
        <TextBox
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="0 5 0 0"
            Text="{Binding Username, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </Grid>
```

**QUESTION:** How is the above Binding working? How does the Binding comes to know which `Username` has been specified? [Here is the link to the complete source code of the MakeReservatoonView.xaml](https://github.com/SingletonSean/reservoom/blob/master/src/Reservoom/Views/MakeReservationView.xaml)

Comment: Read [Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0). Your understanding of "ElementName+Path" vs "DataContext" is wrong. `Text="{Binding Username}"` only works with a DataContext that references an object with a public Username property. The DataContext value may however be inherited from a parent element, by dependency property value inheritance.

Comment: The code you provided is incomplete. Where is the property Username defined? There could be a datacontext binding in the constructor (code behind).

Comment: There will be a `DataContext` defined if binding is being used. If it is not declared within the XAML file then it is likely to be in the associated code behind file.

Comment: @Jake: The complete code is quite big so, I had already provide GitHub URL for the complete source code.

Comment: @Clemens I understand that the DataContext value can be inherited from the parent but if you open the full XAML file (provided Github link), there is no DataContext specified. But per Orace's answer below, I understand that the DataContext has been specified only once at CurrentViewModel's level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In App.xaml.cs, you can see that the MainWindow DataContext is set to `MainViewModel`.
In MainWindow, you have

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />
```

Hence the DataContext of the grid is CurrentViewModel

In ReservationListingViewModel, the MakeReservationCommand set the CurrentViewModel to MakeReservationViewModel who contains the UserName property.